# Toggle div base on body class when body class is " "

Tags: html, css

I am using discourse.org to set up a company forum and therefore have limited access to the site's html code. I have some after header content I only want to show on the landing page.

Right now I can create content that is specific to all the other subpages using the body class like this:

```
.showthisdiv {display:block;}
body.subpageclass1 .showthisdiv {display:none;}
```

This won’t work for the landing page however because the landing page body class name is blank like this:

```
<body class=""> ...
```

How do I declare a class in css when the body class is blank? Does anyone know a way around this? I have been searching for the last day or so, but cannot find it.

Comment: why do you have have to use a class in css? can't you just use the body tag?

Comment: With discourse.org you create content that goes in a wrapper around their platform. This content is mostly uniform throughout the site. Because of that, it is hard to edit html content specifically for one page.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
body[class=""] {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this selector: `body[class=""]`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/endormoon812/dxo5710z/6/

Here is my JSFIDDLE when I try that solution:

Comment: @ClarkVarner remove space here `body [class=""]` so it should become `body[class=""]`